# does plural meaning always be a plural subject

Tags: grammatical-number

I dont know why, but suddenly I confused with a simple question.

> *Geometrical reconstruction of object **corners*** becomes possible.

I am doubted whether the subject is plural. any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to identify the head of the subject noun phrase:

> [ Geometrical **reconstruction** of object corners ]<sub>NP</sub> becomes possible.

The head is *reconstruction*.  It's singular, and therefore the whole noun phrase is singular.  And as you can see, the head isn't always the word that's closest to the verb!

---

The basic form of the sentence is as follows:

> [ **Reconstruction** ]<sub>NP</sub> becomes possible.

As you can see, the noun phrase *reconstruction* is singular.

To get your sentence, first we add the adjective *geometrical*:

> [ Geometrical **reconstruction** ]<sub>NP</sub> becomes possible.

But adding an adjective doesn't change whether it's singular or plural.  It's still singular.

Now, we add a complement.  The noun *reconstruction* can take a preposition phrase as a complement, and in your sentence that preposition phrase is *of object corners*:

> [ Geometrical **reconstruction** of object corners ]<sub>NP</sub> becomes possible.

But adding a complement doesn't change whether it's singular or plural.  It's still singular.

So as you can see, the head is *reconstruction*, even though that isn't the word that's closest to the verb.  *Corners* is not the head of the noun phrase, so it doesn't matter whether that word is singular or plural.

Comment: great, for the very clear explanation.